# Does the discharging rate of a battery depend on the thickness of a conducting wire with which I connect the poles?

Tags: electricity

A simple question to which I don't know the answer though. So maybe indeed a difficult question.
We connect the two terminals of a battery with a conducting wire. Charge flows until the battery is "discharged". Does the velocity with which this discharging occurs depend on the (constant) cross-section of the wire?
If we place a tube between two containers filled with water (one container up high, the other way down) it will surely depend upon the thickness of the tube (its inner cross-section) how long it takes for the container way up to be empty.
I can't imagine though that the discharging depends on the thickness of a conducting wire connecting the poles.

Comment: What do you mean by ‘discharging velocity’?

Comment: The number of electrons that arrive on one side of the battery per second (or leave from the other side per second).

Comment: So the current?

Comment: @jamie1989 ah! I see what you mean. will the current through the wire depend on the thickness of the wire, when we connect the poles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the discharging velocity of a battery depend on the thickness of a conducting wire with which I connect the poles?

Yes, but in some cases, the effect of the thickness of the wire will be negligible.

The total current through the wire will be the emf of the battery divided by the total resistance of the circuit.

The resistance of the circuit depends upon two parts. The (so-called) internal resistance of the battery, and the resistance of the wire connecting the battery electrodes.

If the resistance of the wire is small compared to the the resistance of the battery, then decreasing it even more will have a small impact on the total resistance. The resistance of the wire can be small compared to the resistance of the battery if the wire is *short* or if it is *wide*, (and the wire is made of a good conductor such as copper, or to a lesser extent aluminum).

If the wire is very narrow, or long, then it is possible that increasing the width of the wire will increase the current through it, and consequently, the speed at which the battery discharges.

Comment: Ah yes. So it just depends on the resistance. If the internal resistance is zero (in the ideal case), would this mean that if we make the diameter of the wire twice as large, there would be a four times as high current?

Comment: @DescheleSchilder yes.

Answer (score 1):

If what you mean by 'discharging velocity' is the rate at which electrons pass through the wire or the current through circuit, then yes. The current is related to the resistance of the wire and the voltage of the battery via Ohm's law $I=V/R$ the resistance of the wire can be determined by the resistivity of the wire $\rho$, by $R=\rho L/A$ where $L$ is the length of the wire and $A$ the cross-sectional area of the wire which is related to the thickness by $A=\pi r^2$ where $r$ is the radius of the wire or the thickness (assuming a circular wire). So the current through the wire now becomes $I=VA/\rho L$ The thinner the wire the smaller the cross-sectional area, and so a smaller current passes through. The current determines how fast a battery will discharge.